# Low voltage AC relay

Tags: relay, rectifier

I have an appliance that is turned on by a timer circuit. I would like to switch my furnace blower fan when the appliance is on. For that I figured I would need a relay that I would add in series with the timer. The timer circuit is using AC of 7-8 volt. I bought a 6VAC rated relay, but it doesn't seem to work. It chatters for a while and then stops. Relaxing  the spring within the relay doesn't help, at most it keeps chattering.

Here is the diagram for the circuit with the timer switch only. I need to add a relay here, so that when the timer switch turns on the appliance, the relay closes an separate circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmV5KX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried using a 6VAC (coil rating) relay in series as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyyQQ8.png)</sup>

Information about timer switch [here](http://www.solerpalau-usa.com/pdfs/IOMS/SPTL_Instruction%20Sheet_JULY10.pdf).

This didn't work. The relay that I used was chattering for a short time, the switch wasn't flipped.

Perhaps the AC relay that I used is chattering because the alternating current keeps flipping the switch back and forth. If that is the case, then using a DC relay would avoid this problem. For that I would need to convert the AC current to DC just for the relay. I don't know how to do that or if this is the right idea.

Is converting to DC and using a DC relay the best way to solve the problem  or is there a better approach?

Comment: Is your AC actually 1kHz?

Comment: You appear to have short-circuited your relay?

Comment: DKNguyen - My AC is 50/60Hz.

Comment: Hearth - I think the load is on the appliance and the relay is in series with that, so it shouldn't be a short circuit, right?

Comment: Yes, I think this puts load on the relay, I will try adding relay in parallel.

Comment: We need more information about that timer switch.  Can you link the product?

Comment: Harper - I added information in the post. [Here](http://www.solerpalau-usa.com/pdfs/IOMS/SPTL_Instruction%20Sheet_JULY10.pdf) is the same link.

Answer (score 1):

What are you even trying to do in that circuit?

C1 will limit the current, potentially preventing a sufficiently strong magnetic field to develop in the relay coil.

Then D1 prevents half of the AC current from flowing through the relay coil further weakening it again.

But none of that matters because you have a short-circuit across the relay coil which routes all current away from the relay coil through the short so no current flows through the relay at all.

If you are trying to make AC-DC, that is not how you do it. But changing AC-DC won't fix your problem anyways because it's a relay with an AC coil to begin with.

Relays have a rating for the primary contact which is what they can control. Then they have a rating for the coil which is is used to control the relay. You did not specify what was 6VAC was for.

But that also doesn't matter because your appliance and relay coil are connected incorrectly. Why is your relay coil in series with your appliance? That doesn't make sense.

Normally the relay coil would need to be in parallel with the appliance to do what you want to do. But that doesn't work if your relay coil doesn't also run off the same voltage as your appliance which is what what? 120VAC or 240VAC? What does your relay coil run off of? I don't know, you never actually told us what the relay coil runs off. You just said it was 6VAC but that could mean two things. If the relay coil is 6VAC it won't work and if the primary contacts are 6VAC then the relay coil is probably not 120VAC/240VAC.

You say your timer circuit is using 6VAC, but that kind of doesn't matter if it's supposed to be acting like a switch. If the timer is acting as a switch, it's doing just that: being a switch. It's not supplying its own power to the load. It's just acting as a gatekeeper between the load and power supply for the load, whatever they may be.

The timer circuit is controlling your appliance and I bet your appliance doesn't run off 6VAC. So why do you think the relay coil needs to?

You have not actually labelled any voltages in your schematic either so I can't even tell you how far off base you might be in your misinterpretations of what voltages are required where.

From what I have seen, you need to learn some basic circuits before attempting anything because there is so much wrong here I can't even tell you how to fix it. Information, particularly ratings of everything in your circuit, is also lacking.

Comment: The 6VAC rating is for the relay coil specifically and that should be work for the timer circuit that shows 7-8VAC. I haven't specified ratings for the diode and the capacitor because I don't know how to determine these for my circuit. The circuit that I want to switch is using 24VAC. The appliance is powered by 120VAC in a separate circuit from the timer switch. I didn't want to put a relay on the 120VAC circuit because as I understand it, it is always on, it powers the transformer circuit that powers the timer switch.

Comment: Based on your response, I should be putting the relay in parallel with the appliance. I can try that.

Comment: @ubbb7 Yes. Parallel. But does your appliance actually run off 6-8VAC? Because parallel means both relay coil and appliance must run off the same voltage, and that the timer circuit is acting as a switch that connects or disconnects both from 6VAC.

Comment: The appliance is powered by 110VAC. I updated the post with a diagram of how it works. The timer needs power to function and it draws the power from the circuit that it switches. The timer has just two contacts. When timer passes the current through, that turns on the appliance. I assume it can draw very little current to just to power the timer and keep the appliance off. Perhaps the appliance has a relay inside that switches the appliance on when the timer switch lets enough current through.

Comment: @ubbb7 I guess it is possible that the switch drives 7-8VAC to a relay coil inside the appliance that switches the main 120VAC to the appliance. If that is the case, then putting your relay in parallel with the two contacts on the appliance should do it unless it is not working the way we think it is working. All you should need is a resistor in series with the 6VAC relay coil for it to run off of 7-8VAC. It is sized to limit the current from the higher voltage to the same amount of current that would flow through the relay coil if it were connected to 6VAC.

Comment: I don't have access to the connection between the supply of the 7-8VAC and the appliance. Both the supply and the load of the 7-8VAC circuit is inside the appliance box. So the only parallel connection that I can make is to connect the relay parallel with the timer. However, that doesn't seem right because the timer won't be controlling the current to the relay, so it won't be switching based on the output of the timer. I think you are suggesting using parallel connection as in the answer given by Phil G, but I don't think I have sufficient access to the circuit to create this connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the node between the timer and the load, you need to connect your relay to that point, i.e. in parallel with the load (a resistor in this schematic).

If you don't or you want to put the relay in series as you suggest, and shown in the second schematic, that changes the type of relay you need to use, because what determines whether the relay will operate is the current that flows through the coil. It looks like your first attempt got you a relay that needs more current to hold it in than the load is drawing. You may be able to find a relay that will operate at a low enough current, but the issues is then the voltage dropped across the coil is voltage that is not put across the load. MAny relays will work with both AC or DC voltage across the coil, but often have features that avoid them chattering when running on AC, including shading rings around part of the magnetic circuit. If you can't find a suitable relay, you'd then need to use a bridge rectifier, but then you'd additionally have two diode voltage drops in circuit, and the supply to your load will be getting low.

I'd suggest you reconnect the relay you have to be in parallel with the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwloXf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think both the load and the supply is inside the appliance box, so I think I won't be able to implement the circuit in the first diagram. [Here](https://www.newark.com/potter-brumfield-te-connectivity/k10p-11a15-6/relay-dpdt-120vac-30vdc-15a/dp/18M9150?ost=18M9150&ddkey=https%3Aen-US%2FElement14_US%2Fsearch) is the relay that I used. It specifically says that it can be used in AC circuits. The load is not actually powering the appliance, I think it is powering some relay that controls the appliance on/off state. Still it is important to let enough current through.

Comment: From that datasheet, you need 6V for that relay to pull in, which means that you can't afford to drop much across the circuit you're putting in series, and that's probably true of whatever relay is inside the box too, or you risk either or both of the relays not pulling in properly. You're probably stuck with using a current sensing relay, that doesn't impose any voltage drop  https://www.ecmweb.com/power-quality-reliability/article/20896828/the-basics-of-currentsensing-relays